# Class name is added to the html element, but the css is missing

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css, vite, nuxtjs3

When in development mode, I can't get the responsive modifiers classes to produce a styled output in my Nuxt3 application. For example when adding:

```
bg-green
```

everything works, hot-reloading displays green background, but then when adding:

```
lg:bg-red-500
```

the class name is added to the html element, but the css is missing.

I tried tailwind.config.js safelist option but that's not ideal and compiling css and hot-reloading takes around 15s on my macbook pro... Any ideas?

I'm using Vite with Nuxt.

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: A codepen would be great!

Comment: I'll try to get a minimum code soon on codesandbox. If you struggle with this problem too, see my answer below, it works!

Comment: Some proper reproduction with more details regarding all the used versions could have helped quite well.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0):

I created a workaround by using Tailwind CLI to compile my CSS separately instead of trying to integrate Tailwind into Nuxt 3.
It's suggested on TailwindCSS website:
[it-just-isn-t-working-properly](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#it-just-isn-t-working-properly)